# What is the method to use a django model in a non django application?

Tags: django, model, import, external

I am trying out [webpython.codepoint.net](http://webpython.codepoint.net) as a way of learning python web programming at a basic level and I want to use a django model in it, as a way of including a django model in a non django application.

What is the best way to go about it? If my app is part of a project called projectA and the app directory is call appDir, would it by a simple matter of doing something like `from projectA/appDir import modelX` or would a whole lot more be required.

I am a python as well as a django newbie, so please be patient.

I would also be interested in any other similarly basic or perhaps not so basic python web programming tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you need to have the configuration of your database defined. That's normally handled using an environment variable called DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE pointing to your django project settings model

However you can also [use settings without setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module)